# Como saber en que fila estoy haciendo click, para poder realizar petciones POST

Tags: php, wordpress

Estoy realizando una aplicación en PHP, y estoy atascado en como saber en que fila estoy haciendo clic, para obtener su id, y otros valores, para poder realizar una petición POST.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<form method="post">
                <?php
                $cont = 0;
                foreach ($lista_valores as $key => $value) {
                    $cont++;
                    $nombre = $value['name'];
                    $zona_residencia = $value['Zone'];
                    $fecha_comienzo = $value['start'];
                    $fecha_fin = $value['end'];
          
                    $id = $value["Id"];
                   
                    echo "<tr>
                <td >$id</td>
                <td>$nombre</td>
                <td>$zona_residencia</td>
                <td>$fecha_comienzo</td>
                <td>$fecha_fin</td>
                
                <td>";

                    
                        echo "
            <input type='submit'  name='update".$cont."' class='page-litle-action'  
 value='Actualizar'>
         </td></tr>
                    
           
             </tbody>
        </form>";
                    
                }


                ?>
                 </table>
                <hr>
```

Cada vez que pulse al botón update, tiene que realizar una serie de tareas, que son:

```
<?php
            if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
                $id_ = $_POST[''];
                global $wpdb;
                $tabla_actualizar = "{$wpdb->prefix}nombre_tabla";
                get_campaign_by_id($id_, $tabla_actualizar);
            }
```

He creado un contador para diferenciar los distintos botones, pero no consigo realizar el post. Ni siquiera entra en él. ¿Existe alguna manera de poder realizar la petición? ¿Es posible diferenciar los botones? Los botones se crean con el nombre update1, update2.....
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Y si le pones el `<form>` solo al `input` en lugar de toda la tabla?  De esa forma separas los inputs, cada uno es un formulario.  Luego en cada `form` le agregas un `input` tipo `hidden` con el `name` **id** y el valor de `$value["Id"]` y se lo pasas por `POST['id']` a tu php y asi puedes continuar. Eso funcionaria, aunque seguro que hay otras formas.

Comment: Funciona.  Solución ingeniosa.

Comment: Bueno, otra forma seria simplemente cambiar los inputs de tipo `submit` por `checkbox` y ponerles de valor el id, y dejar el `form` como está con un único botón al final de `submit`.  Así puedes realizar la siguiente acción sobre varios de ellos usando el mismo name (por ejemplo `ids` para todos pero terminado en `[]`,  es decir, `name="ids[]"` así pasarias un array de datos al php que podrias recorrer y actualizar varios a la vez.  Es que tampoco tengo claro si así te interesaba o solo pretendias ejecutar esa acción una vez solo.

Comment: O lo mismo pero con type="radio" y usando el mismo name para todos (sin los `[]` esta vez)  y dejar el boton submit al final. Así solo tendrias tambien un solo `form` pero solo funcionaria de uno en uno. Como gustes.

Comment: Lo pondré en práctica en mi próximo plugin. Gracias, y es verdad que la imaginación es más importante que el conocimiento. Saludos y feliz 2022

Comment: Igualmente! :-)